# when call up from Background my Codename App Shows bug

Tags: codenameone

i receives error each time I call up my codenameone app from android background.
the error show that components already add to the location.
I think it calls the start function again when coming from background.
please how do I fix this ?

Comment: Please provide additional information(at least code) for your question.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/) `start()` is indeed invoked on app resume from suspension to notify you of this situation. You need to handle that correctly as our default code does.

You can simulate this in the device simulator using the pause/resume menu option.